# Publication Of 50 pages

Tags: soft-question, journals, career, mathematical-writing, advice

Does anyone know of a research journal in mathematics that is willing to publish 50 pages of peer-review research? I would like to submit research that explores how to develop predicate models for analyzing the progression of recursive sequences. It is a bit too long for the Monthly and too short for a Monograph. Thanks.

Comment: many suggestions are at https://mathoverflow.net/q/15366/11260

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I don't think "peer-review research" counts as "expository work".

Comment: well, many of the journals in that extensive list are described as publishing long articles, and they are all peer-reviewed...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Well, I feel like many journals in general publish long articles.  (The OP's mention of the Monthly and Monographs are quite special.)  Is there some sort of reason that journals which publish expository work would be more likely to publish long research articles?

Comment: A few months ago, I gave [this suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386081/where-to-publish-a-long-classification/386089#386089)

Comment: Any journal publishes articles of any length unless they explicitly state otherwise. That said, longer articles tend to be harder to get accepted than shorter ones.

Comment: Most recent issue of J Amer Math Soc https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2022-35-01/ contains Geometric stochastic heat equations
Y. Bruned, F. Gabriel, M. Hairer and L. Zambotti.
J. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (2022), 1-80 and Nilpotent structures and collapsing Ricci-flat metrics on the K3 surface
Hans-Joachim Hein, Song Sun, Jeff Viaclovsky and Ruobing Zhang.
J. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (2022), 123-209 and The Seiberg-Witten equations and the length spectrum of hyperbolic three-manifolds
Francesco Lin and Michael Lipnowski.
J. Amer. Math. Soc. 35 (2022), 233-293.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/advances-in-mathematics/vol/327 contains A canonical torsion theory for pro-p Iwahori–Hecke modules
Rachel Ollivier, Peter Schneider
Pages 52-127; Finite W-algebras for 
Alberto De Sole, Victor G. Kac, Daniele Valeri
Pages 173-224; Donaldson–Thomas transformations of moduli spaces of G-local systems
Alexander Goncharov, Linhui Shen
Pages 225-348; Derived Galois deformation rings
S. Galatius, A. Venkatesh
Pages 470-623; More on gauge theory and geometric Langlands
Edward Witten
Pages 624-707 and two other 50+ page papers.

Comment: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2021/194-3 has Polynomial structure of Gromov–Witten potential of quintic 3-folds
Pages 585-645 by Huai-Liang Chang, Shuai Guo, Jun Li; Finite-time singularity formation for 1, solutions to the incompressible Euler equations on ℝ3
Pages 647-727 by Tarek M. Elgindi; Chow groups and -derivatives of automorphic motives for unitary groups
Pages 817-901 by Chao Li, Yifeng Liu so it appears that papers of 50 pages or more are not uncommon.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I have had a paper rejected from a journal for being too short, and the journal had no explicit length requirements. The referee said that the paper was very well written and interesting, just too short. It has since been accepted at a journal for shorter papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was asked a long time ago, and never got an answer, but did receive some useful comments. The short answer is **there are hundreds of journals that would publish such a paper.** In some fields of mathematics, 50 pages is a totally reasonable length. For example, I've seen papers of that length in Annals, Transactions, Advances, Topology, Geometry & Topology, AGT, JPAA, HHA, New York Journal of Math, Journal of Algebra, Expositiones, Applied Categorical Structures, TAC, Compositio, Math Z, Journal of K-theory, etc. The point is, in homotopy theory, papers of this length are normal.

As others have pointed out, some papers do have limits (e.g., Proceedings of the AMS only allows papers under 15 pages, and Memoirs of the AMS only allows longer papers), but they are in the minority by far. I estimate fewer than 10% of journals have a page limit.

That said, it's also true that, all things being equal, **longer papers are slightly harder to publish than shorter papers**, for two reasons. First, they take longer to referee. Second, they are held to a slightly higher standard by the editors, because they take up more pages in the journal. In my area, it's common for young authors to write longer papers, and eventually learn how to write shorter papers, either by splitting off pieces or by relying more on earlier work and streamlining technical arguments (rather than spelling out every single detail). Folks who want to make the literature more friendly (and really write proofs where they really spell out all the details) often write books. It's good to get into the practice of discerning when a paper can be split in two, or when a bit of work you've done is already publishable and can be submitted, even if you plan to keep investigating and follow it up with a sequel.