# Mathematical journals that accept long papers (up to 100 pages)

Tags: soft-question, journals

I have a problem with finding a suitable mathematical journal (maybe not of the highest level) that accepts longer paper (say 100 pages). I know only two such journals: Memoirs of AMS and Dissert.Math.
But both journals now are in Q1 quartile, so are very selective, without any chances to be accepted there.

In fact, "Dissertationes Mathematicae" was created in 1951 (as "Rozprawy Matematyczne") with the purpose of publishing good Ph.D. Theses and indeed some time ago it was quite real to be accepted there. But since 2019 when they entered to the Q1 quartile this journal accepts only papers of exceptional quality (so far higher than an average Ph.D. Thesis).

So, what would be your suggestion concerning journals for longer papers (at the moment I would not like to consider splitting the long paper into smaller pieces). Thanks for the advise (I suspect that many mathematicians had such problems in mind, so the collective experience had to elaborate some helpful answer here).

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409158/publication-of-50-pages

Comment: Is it original research or rather an expository paper? -- I'd guess that if it is original research, a 100-pages-paper needs to be pretty strong / important to find readers (or if it is not, it needs to be at least written *very* well)(?)

Comment: @StefanKohl It is both: research and expository, to be precise I have problems with finding a suitable journal for this preprint (which took me several years of life): https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02017 But this is a bit old-fashion topic (metrization of functors), so high level journals will reject it as being no so interesting for modern readers and bla-bla-bla, but I am interested in publishing it at all because too much time was digged into its writing.

Comment: Any probability theory journal nowadays? :)

Comment: I find it quite disturbing that professional mathematicians use the notion of Q1/Q2 journal, mostly based on low-cost statistics, as a serious criterion. The level of journal is likely to evolute. For instance, a top journal might become of poor level because of a poor editorial policy (which evolutes with time and renewal — or non-renewal— of the editorial board), or can experience a drop in the level of submissions (e.g., because of boycott of an agressive publisher), etc.

Answer (score 12):

Applied Categorical Structures https://www.springer.com/journal/10485/ seems to match the topic of your paper and fairly regularly publishes 70+ pages papers. It is a Q2 journal according to Scimago.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, a good choice.

Answer (score 11):

[*Lecture Notes in Mathematics*](https://www.springer.com/series/304) (Springer) has a *minimum* of 100 pages.  But it may not be "peer reviewed" in the conventional sense.

Comment: I might be mistaken but my impression was that most monographs and Springer lecture notes were peer reviewed pretty much up to the same standards of rigour as a typical journal article.

Answer (score 8):

Another option to publish can be *[SpringerBriefs in Mathematics.](https://www.springer.com/series/10030)* This is a book series for books with 50 to 125 pages. All books are peer-reviewed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggesting. Looks like very suitable.

Answer (score 6):

There is a newly-formed journal [Memoirs of the European Mathematical Society](https://ems.press/journals/mems) that has a minimum limit of 80 pages.

It will issue the first volume this year, so I cannot evaluate their quality standards.

Answer (score 6):

The [Annales de la Faculté des Sciences de Toulouse](https://afst.centre-mersenne.org/) doesn't have any page limit for papers. For instance, in 2022 they published [a paper of 382 pages](https://afst.centre-mersenne.org/articles/10.5802/afst.1697/).

Answer (score 4):

Publishing a paper 50-100 pages long can indeed be a problem.
However many journals actually like long papers (they are likely to have
higher citation rate:-) though they do not advertise this. Specifically I recommend the following course of action: look at some long papers in your area, and notice where they are published.
For more than 100 pages, there are several excellent online-only journals, which usually have no size restriction.

Answer (score 2):

The MDPI journal [Mathematics](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/mathematics/about) states that:

> Our aim is to encourage scientists to publish their experimental and
> theoretical results in as much detail as possible. There is no
> restriction on the length of the papers. The full account of the
> research must be provided so that the results can be reproduced.

It's a Q2 journal, which could well be what you are looking for.

MDPI is an agressive publisher, you might want to read this [discussion.](https://paolocrosetto.wordpress.com/2021/04/12/is-mdpi-a-predatory-publisher/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes I know this MDPI. They usually want 1600 Swiss franks for publication and I do not have such money to pay. On the other hand I have published 4 papers in their journal "Axioms" and all four were for for 0 franks (in my special case).

Comment: I was invited to review an 80-page mathematics paper for an MDPI journal, and was given the standard MDPI time of 1 week (maximum 2 weeks) to complete my review, which was then shortened to 3 days as they had already received other reviews. When I said I'd need more time to review an 80-page paper, they cancelled my invitation. This speaks to the quality of peer review that one might expect for long papers in such journals. @TarasBanakh

Comment: On the outrageous Article Processing Charge (APC) imposed by MDPI: According to their own [website][1], the APC is needed in part to cover the cost of peer review. Thus the naïve expectation would be that each reviewer gets their share of the publication fee. However, should it make you feel uncomfortable that reviewers are actively benefiting from this scheme; do not despair! Of course you won't be paid out money --- at most you'll get a discount on your own future publications in an affiliated journal! I think this says it all...

  [1]: https://www.mdpi.com/journal/mathematics/apc

Comment: To be blunt, whenever I get email from them, I mark it as spam.

Answer (score 2):

I recall here [my answer to a similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386081/where-to-publish-a-long-classification/386089#386089): a journal which accepts long papers and has also an illustrious history is the Journal published by Castelnuovo Institute of Mathematics of the Sapienza University of Rome, i. e. the "**[Rendiconti di Matematica e delle sue Applicazioni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendiconti_di_Matematica_e_delle_sue_Applicazioni)**". I recall the statements one can read on the [homepage of the Journal](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/ricerca/rendiconti/):

> The Journal "Rendiconti di Matematica e delle sue Applicazioni" is regularly issued since 1914.
> The Journal traditionally publishes high-quality research articles in Pure and Applied Mathematics and adheres to the EMS Code of Practice.

> Articles of any length are considered for publication. Submission of surveys, of articles of foundational nature, of doctoral dissertations etc. is also encouraged.
> Every article submitted is subjected to a first screening by the Editorial board: if the manuscript meets the journal’s basic requirements, it will be sent to a referee for a single blind peer review process. Once a paper is accepted it goes immediately into production and published online shortly after the approval of galley proofs.